# how to select randomly from the entered inputs in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am making a program where we can select randomly from the entered names. When the entered names are 10, it will pick only one name randomly and if the user entered 'Y' from the roll, it will pick a random name again from the entered names before.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int countname = 10;
    char roll;
    cout << "Please enter all the name of the entries: " << endl;

    while (countname --) {
         cin >> name;
    }
   do {
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Entries count: 10/10" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "THE WINNER IS: " << name << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "CONGRATULATIONS TO YOU " << name << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Roll again? [Y]/[N]: ";
    cin >> roll;
   }
   while (roll == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose you know you memorize only the last read name ?

Comment: If you want to choose randomly, you had better learn to generate random numbers. Then learn to generate random integers in the range `[0,10]`. Then select one string at random from a container of 10 strings. Meanwhile, in parallel, you may learn how to collect ten strings from the user and store them in a container.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all 10 names. You should use container - [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) suitable for this. For example

```
std::string name;
std::vector<std::string> names;
while (countname --) {
    cin >> name;
    names.push_back(name);
}
```

For random number you can use this piece of code

```
#include <random>
std::random_device dev;
std::mt19937 rng(dev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> rand(0,9);
std::cout << rand(rng) << std::endl;
```

And print random name like this

```
const std::string winner = names[rand(rng)]
std::cout << winner << std::endl;
```

Result

```
Please enter all the name of the entries: 
name_0
name_1
name_2
name_3
name_4
name_5
name_6
name_7
name_8
name_9
--------------------------
Entries count: 10/10
--------------------------
THE WINNER IS: name_3
--------------------------
CONGRATULATIONS TO YOU name_3
--------------------------
Roll again? [Y]/[N]: Y
--------------------------
Entries count: 10/10
--------------------------
THE WINNER IS: name_5
--------------------------
CONGRATULATIONS TO YOU name_5
--------------------------
Roll again? [Y]/[N]:
```

Comment: Side note: if using MinGW's g++ before gcc 9.3 watch out: `std::random_device` is deliberately broken and always returns the same number. That means if you're programming on Windows, not using Visual Studio  and don't already know what tools you are using, odds are it's backed by MinGW's GCC and you should check the version.

Comment: No worries. I just mention it here because it can be a really nasty shock. In a perfect world it's not something you should have to know about, but the Standard gave `random_device` a lot of wiggle room, too much imho even though I understand why they did it, and the result is 100% compliant, 100% useless implementations.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are only storing the last name, instead, you should store all the names in an array.
2. For finding a random name in the array, generate a random index between 0 to 9 ( you can use `rand() % 10` ) and the name at that index will be the random name.

Comment: `rand` is likely more than good enough for this, but for future projects where randomness is more important consider using the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library. [Here's a good video explaining why](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).